# Easiest way to fill datagridview with dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am using dapper.net to make a sql query filling a plain class.

I looked at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) and didnt really understand. When I did `.datasource = mylist` I got many rows but all the columns were empty. I named a column id thinking it will autofill but it didn't.

How do i fill a datagridview with `IEnumerable<myclass>` ?

Comment: can't you just say `datagridview.source=DataTable` ?

Comment: @Andrew: Thats what i did to get a bunch of rows but theres nothing in it

Comment: Well, verify that Datatable has data!

Comment: @Andrew: It is, id is long but that shouldnt affect anything?

Comment: If you have correct data in the datatable, then, perhaps, you trying to assign it to the wrong datagridview? Try surrounding your assignment to try-catch statement and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Andrew well empty rows are being created because of that one line (`datasource=mylist`). I'm asking why isn't it being populated? Is the column name suppose to be the same as the field name? Maybe its because i have them as fields instead of getter/setters?

Answer (score 1):

Change the fields into a property

Example

```
class A { public int id; }
```

To

```
class A { public int id{get;set;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class property name must match the table column name.

Example

SQL

```
SELECT First_Name FROM Employees
```

Class

```
class Employee { public string First_Name {get;set;} }
```

*Note: It is not case sensitive.